# How can I report to Drupal what is the translation in a language of a string passed to t()?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I'm using Drupal 7. I see that the `t()` function is responsible for translating terms. Where do I go to find the list of translatable terms? For example, suppose I have `t('hello world')` in my code.  What file do I edit to tell Drupal 7 that the French version of "hello world" is *bonjour toute le monde*?

Answer (score 2):

- You could browse to the Translate interface page
  (/admin/config/regional/translate/translate).
- You could use a .po file and import it (en/admin/config/regional/translate/import).

You'll have to enable the Locale module for this (it's in core).
More information is available on [Translating a site interface to different languages](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/locale).

Comment: Thanks, how do I create a .po file for my Hello World example?

Comment: The easiest way would be to export your terms first (/admin/config/regional/translate/export). That way you'll have a .po file that you can edit. If you translate one term you'll have the complete syntax.

Comment: I just want to notify that you string would be available only if it appear in the foreign language at least one time. For example, you are looking for `hello world` but if you didn't see it in the french part of your website you'll not able to find it in the admin.